# MVC 4 Creates a new database instead of using the one specified in web.config file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have created a new MVC 4 project, Build and Run -> All Successful

Try to login -> New Database is created in SQL Express (Database name: xyz) => All good so far...

Now, I want to add a new table called "ABCD"  in SQL Express (to above xyz Database). How can I access this table in Visual Studio solution? There is no Entity Framework model to go and update it manually?

However, I have added a class called `ABCD` in the Models folder

Created a new controller for ABCD with a new `Data Context Class` but when I ran the solution, it is created a new Database instead of using the default database mentioned in Web.config file

Can someone please let me know how can I fix this issue with detailed steps?

## Here is my DataContext class:

using System.Data.Entity;

namespace _1024.Models
{
    public class _1024Context : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to drop and regenerate your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, add the following
        // code to the Application_Start method in your Global.asax file.
        // Note: this will destroy and re-create your database with every model change.
        // 
        // System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<_1024.Models._1024Context>());

```
    public _1024Context() : base("name=_1024Context")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ABCD> ABCDs { get; set; }
}
```

}

## Here is the Web.config File:

```
<configSections>
<!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />


</configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-_1024-20130606134952;Integrated Security=SSPI"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="_1024Context" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=_1024Context-20130606135301; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Are you adding `ABCD` to the `Data Context Class` as a `DbSet`? , you should post the code for your `Data Context Class`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use new connection string if you want to use existing database. In your connection strings you have two different initial catalog that means two different database.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write like this without the "name=" first. This works for me.

```
public _1024Context() : base("_1024Context")
```